# Mutate using distinct and ifelse dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with duplicated names. I want to make a new column with the values 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE) if a name is duplicated.

The is the code I use:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% mutate(Duplicated = ifelse(distinct(`First name` == T, 0, 1)))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "logical".
```

or

```
dat %>% mutate(Duplicated = ifelse(distinct(`First name`), 0, 1))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "logical".
```

However, I get the errors you can see above.

Another Idea is to use group_by and then counting the counts. Like:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(`Last name`) %>%
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Dpulicated = ifelse(N > 1, 1,0)
```

However, ich can´t return the original dataframe after group_by

Comment: If I understood your question, you are looking for `duplicated` instead of `dinstinct`.

Comment: Yes, if a name appears more than once it should be the value 1 otherwise the value 0 should be imputed.

Comment: @patL is pointing out that a function `duplicated()` exists and is vectorized. However, it will return FALSE for the first non-duplicated entry of a repeated value. You can obtain your desired result with `as.numeric(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast =T))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `summarise(N= n())`, you could do `mutate(N = n())`.

Here is how I would do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame("last_name" = c("Smith","James","Smith","Smith","Messi"),
                "value" = c(15,26,7,38,90))

df = df %>%
  group_by(last_name) %>%
  mutate(n = n(),
         is_dupe = ifelse(n > 1,TRUE,FALSE))
```

Comment: `ifelse(n > 1,TRUE,FALSE)` gives exactly the same result as `n > 1`